# Are Azure DevOps APIs language agnostic?

Tags: c#, azure, dart, devops

I've written small programs in C# that integrate with Azure DevOps and perform actions on WorkItems and complete other small tasks. I accomplished this using the APIs provided by Microsoft as well as the NuGet packages they provide in order to successfully integrate with DevOps.

I want to create a similar application using Dart/Flutter, largely as a practical exercise that has a useful product. However I'm unsure whether doing this in a language that is not C# is actually feasible. Since the integration with DevOps required the NuGet packages provided by Microsoft, and the fact that these don't exist for Dart, would I still be able to write a Dart app that could communicate with DevOps?

Azure DevOps APIs: `https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/?view=azure-devops-rest-5.1`

NuGet: `Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.Client etc.`

Answer (score 1):

Given that the API is referred to as a REST API returning XML or JSON data, and there are client libraries in a number of different languages (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/?view=azure-devops-rest-5.1#client-libraries) this should be possible.

Worst-case is you'll end up talking to the HTTP endpoints directly, rather than via some helpful wrapper library, as is your case with C#.

Comment: Another option, if there are no libraries in the chosen language, would be to generate client code using the OpenAPI specifications.

Comment: @ColinM Could you explain some more about this? How would I go about doing that?

Comment: @Jake12342134 [The following readme](https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-codegen/tree/master/samples/client/petstore/dart/swagger) contains some information regarding Dart generation, particularly with the [Swagger-Codegen](https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-codegen)

Answer (score 0):

Given that the API is referred to as a REST API returning XML or JSON data, and there are client libraries in a number of different languages (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/?view=azure-devops-rest-5.1#client-libraries) this should be possible.